# What software they use to create video like this?

Tags: flash, video

I am very curious to know what software would they use to create video like this?

http://vimeo.com/21237756

Is it flash?

How can they design the sketches well?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I guess an artist would draw the sketches which are used within flash.